# Newly created category does not show category

Tags: posts, categories

I'm creating New Posts in WordPress when i try to add New category and click on Add Category its does not show created category so default category used as category

Its create create category but not showing in category list in new post page.

I don't know whats the problem.

Comment: Please don't use the wordpress.org tag. Also, your question is not clear at all. First you say that you cannot create a new category, then you say the new category is created but not showing on post edit page. Please [edit] your question and clearly state what is happening. Also state whether you are using default categories, are you talking about default posts, or custom post types.

Comment: done. please now check.

Comment: What theme are you using. Set debug to true in wp-config.php, if you get no errors, try deactivating your plugins one by one and check after each one if the problem still exists. You should also try switching to one of the bundled themes and check if you have the same problem

Comment: Its not theme problem. Its new post . Its publish post page. I'm using Nginx latest , php latest

Comment: Please first do as I said in the previous comment. It seems that something in your theme or a plugin is causing this problem. This is not normal wordpress behaviour.

Comment: okay i will try. here is console log XML or text declaration not at start of entity admin-ajax.php:2 post-new.php:2

Comment: Did you make any changes to the core files?

Comment: Nope. Why do i do that? Its maybe theme problem. i created my own wp theme and not faced any problem with category but now facing.